# How to extract result from org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggest object on scala

Tags: scala, playframework, elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a suggester using elasticsearch, I constructed the query class and after execution I'm getting this `Suggest` result and I'm not able to extract the actual text from it. I'm trying this on the scala console now.

```
scala> result
res75: org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggest =
{
  "first_name" : [ {
    "text" : "hari",
    "offset" : 0,
    "length" : 4,
    "options" : [ {
      "text" : "HARIA",
      "score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "text" : "HARID",
      "score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "text" : "HARIDAS",
      "score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "text" : "HARIDASN",
      "score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "text" : "HARIDASNSS",
      "score" : 1.0
    }]
  } ]
}

scala> result.getSuggestion()
<console>:25: error: not enough arguments for method getSuggestion: (x$1: String)T.
Unspecified value parameter x$1.
              result.getSuggestion()
```

How can I extract the `text` from above result. I can see that `result.getSuggestion()` is the method which will give this, but for that I have to pass some map or other function as argument to it. I'm not sure about how to do that.. Could you please help on this ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/evanwong/6511366  - This is kinda saving my time. If I get it complete will post the result.

Answer (score 0):

I got the working solution from this link - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/FwRv0D5qIi8

The solution is -

```
    import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder._
    import org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.CompletionSuggestionBuilder
    import org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.CompletionSuggestion

    // Build query for searching the client.
    var suggester = new CompletionSuggestionBuilder("first_name")
    suggester.text(query)
    suggester.field("suggest")
    suggester.size(5)
    var suggestions = client.prepareSuggest("autocomplete")
                      .addSuggestion(suggester)
                      .execute()
                      .actionGet()

    val suggest = suggestions.getSuggest()

    if (suggest.size > 0) {
      val optIter = suggest
                  .iterator()
                  .next()
                  .getEntries()
                  .get(0)
                  .iterator()

      while(optIter.hasNext()){
          println(optIter.next().getText())
      }
    }
```

I know this question was little specific to particular API usage. I'm not accepting my answer my self now :)